# How to properly return a List<struct> from a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service, and I want to return a `List<ThePassenger>` to the client. In my interface section I have declared a function that returns `List<ThePassenger>` and implemented it.

```
[OperationContract]
List<ThePassenger> GetPassengers();
```

And this is ThePassenger struct:

```
[DataContract]
public struct ThePassenger
{
    [DataMember]
    public string firstname;
    [DataMember]
    public string lastname;
    [DataMember]
    public string passport;
    [DataMember]
    public string flight;
    [DataMember]
    public string ticket;
    [DataMember]
    public string meal;
    [DataMember]
    public string baggage;
    [DataMember]
    public string bookingkey;
};
```

In client's service reference settings I set my collection to `Generic.List`,
but when I run this code on client:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
client.GetPassengers();
```

I get `System.ObjectDisposedException: cannot access a disposed object.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one, please change your fields into proper Properties. And use a proper naming convention. Also, post the server side code and the Stacktrace.

Comment: Side-note: mutable structs are [Considered Harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Comment: We need a full stack trace for this. The problem seems to be inside client.GetPassengers(); call, but you didn't provided the code of this method

Comment: Can you show your implementation for `GetPassengers()`?

Comment: SIDE NOTE: Since, COLLECTION is very much specific to .Net, WCF does not expose it to the metadata of the service. WCF provides dedicated marshaling rules for collection. Collection will be exposed as array in service metadata... Ergo use [] instead of IEnumerable<T> or List<T>

Answer (score -1):

looks like client proxy object is getting disposed or not initialized properly, try below mentioned code.

```
MyServiceClient client = null;
using(clinet = new MyServiceClient())
{
    client.GetPassengers();
}
```

Comment: -1: WCF proxy classes are one of the very few places where you should not use a `using` block.